# Text Display in MS Chart in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I am using MS Chart in my application.My problem is that when data increases in volume details of x-axis(text or heading) misses as some of the text is shown and some is missed.

Snap is here,

[image]

Plz. help.

Thanks in advance,
Supriya

Comment: What do you think should happen or what is you want ! !

Comment: As in chart there are 11 bars but the text associated with all 11 is not being shown while I want to show the text(or heading) for all 11.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this problem is that you can add a tooltip to the bars on the `DataBound` event so you can show the full name on mouse over. Otherwise you can show names in short words (e.g.Jyoti...).